# PHPUnit error undefined variable

Tags: php, error-handling, zend-framework2, phpunit

I'm running PHPunit to test my ZF2 application. I tried it on my Windows machine (under xampp), and it worked fine. But when I moved it to a virtual Ubuntu 14.10 server, I keep getting the following error with every test:

```
Undefined variable: services
```

I went to /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and set error reporting as follows:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```

The code the tests are pointing to is from one of my Module.php files

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $sharedEventManager =  $event->getApplication()
        ->getEventManager()
        ->getSharedManager();

    $sharedEventManager->attach('user', 'log-fail', function($event) use ($services) {
        $username = $event->getParam('username');


        $log = $services->get('log');
        $log->warn("Error logging user [$username]");
    });
}
```

It's specifically complaining about the line `$sharedEventManager->attach('user', 'log-fail', function($event) use ($services)`. Like I said, I tried editing the php.ini files to suppress warnings like this, but it isn't working. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Check your PHP Version on `virtual Ubuntu 14.10 server`.

Comment: The variable $services is not defined in the code you have shown.

Comment: I'm running php 5.5.12

Comment: What's ur PHP Version on Windows Machine.

Comment: The Windows version is 5.5.11.

Comment: The example is actually from a (very badly-written) book about ZF2. I don't have it on hand right now, so it's possible I missed something when writing the original code. I'm quite proficient with most of PHP, but some of the newer concepts like namespaces and the way it uses closures are still new to me. I'll look at the book again when I get home--it's possible I'll find the solution there.

Comment: What's your book name??

Comment: Learn ZF2: Learning By Example by Slavey Karadzhov. It's filled with typos and missing pieces, and the explanations often miss crucial pieces of information.

Comment: Try to add this line `$services = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();` before `$sharedEventManager->attach(`

Comment: The question should be: Why does not this test fail on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. It was just as Indrasinh Bihola said: I'd left a part out. Well, the book did. The snippet I borrowed is from an earlier section, but it skips crucial parts, and gives no indication of where the original part is (37 pages back!). Also, not to make excuses, but I've never used closures in PHP and I had no idea what use($services) actually did. Now I do. I won't make the same mistake again.

Comment: But yes, I do feel pretty dumb right now, as well I should. :(